# how to detect flutter red screen in appium?

Tags: appium, flutter-test, appium-java

so, I am using appium inspector to write a script for mobile testing for a school project.

my problem is that I don't know how to detect this red screen resulted for flutter app.

this image is just example for what I mean :

[image]

so I want to write in my scripts whenever the result is this red error screen, fail the test.

but the red screen in appium inspector is just a normal android view with no access to the text displayed, so how can I write automated test for it if I don't have a unique identifier for these screens ?

and these are the visible attributes for me in appium inspector for the shown red screen:

| Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- |
| elementId | 00000000-0000-07a4-0000-006700000011 |
| index | 1 |
| package | com.example.sw_code |
| class | android.view.View |
| text | resource-id |
| checkable | false |
| checked | false |
| clickable | false |
| enabled | true |
| focusable | false |
| focused | false |
| long-clickable | false |
| password | false |
| scrollable | false |
| selected | false |
| bounds | [0,294][1440,2579] |
| displayed | true |

Answer (score 0):

Flutter UI attributes are not visible to Appium's UiAutomator2 or XCUITest drivers that we typically use to automate Android and iOS applications respectively.

For this reason, Appium folks have created a separate driver to test flutter based applications. Check it out here: https://github.com/appium-userland/appium-flutter-driver

Note that this driver is in experimental phase. You will need to weigh pros and cons and go for this driver.

The other option is to use flutter's own flutter driver (link: https://docs.flutter.dev/testing), but know that it needs Dart programming language.